# Problem with 'poorly written script', causing high server resource consumption

Tags: script, server

I have had my magento store and admin taken offline by my server host (siteground) due to excessive consumption of shared server resources. They told me it was due to a poorly written script which was 'hogging the server'...
Here is some of the queries which were said to be a problem...

**Executed 76 min ago for 31 sec on Database --> girachac_magen80.**
        INSERT INTO `8s8_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) IS NOT NULL, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value), 0) AS `tax_class_id`, 1 AS `price_type`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_pr
 ice.value, 0) AS `special_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_percent`, IF(ta_price.value IS NULL, 0, ta_price.value) AS `orig_price`, IF(IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) IS NOT NULL AND IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) < IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFN
 ULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value), IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROU
 ND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL), IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_da
 te.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value)) AS `price`, IF(IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) IS NOT NULL AND IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) < IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_speci
 al_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFN
 ULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value), IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL), IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_dat
 e, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value)) AS `min_price`, IF(IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 1
 00, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) IS NOT NULL AND IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) < IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_s
 pecial_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value), IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL), IF(IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) >
  0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website
 _date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) / 100), 2), ta_price.value)) AS `max_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (tp.min_price / 100)), 2), NULL) AS `tier_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (tp.min_price / 100)), 2), NULL) AS `base_tier`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) AS `group_price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, ROUND(ta_price.value - (ta_price.value * (IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) / 100)), 2), NULL) AS `base_group_price`, gp.price AS `group_price_percent` FROM `8s8_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` CROSS JOIN `8s8_customer_group` AS `cg` CROS
 S JOIN `8s8_core_website` AS `cw` INNER JOIN `8s8_core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id INNER JOIN `8s8_core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_index_group_price` AS `gp` ON gp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND gp.website_id = cw.website_id AND gp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id A
 ND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 121 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 121 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `ta_price_type` ON ta_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price_type.attribute_id = 123 AND ta_price_type.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 75 AND ta_price.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_price.attribute_id = 76 AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_
 entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='bundle') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id,
  -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (ta_price_type.value=1) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price_type` = VALUES(`price_type`), `special_price` = VALUES(`special_price`), `tier_percent` = VALUES(`tier_percent`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`), `group_price_percent` = VALUES(`group_price_percent

**Executed 6 min ago for 31 sec on Database --> girachac_magen80.**
        INSERT INTO `8s8_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, 0 AS `tax_class_id`, 0 AS `price_type`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) AS `special_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_percent`, IF(ta_price.value IS NULL, 0, ta_price.value) AS `orig_price`, 0 AS `price`, 0 AS `min_price`, 0 AS `max_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL
 , 0, NULL) AS `tier_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, 0, NULL) AS `base_tier`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0), NULL) AS `group_price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0), NULL) AS `base_group_price`, gp.price AS `group_price_percent` FROM `8s8_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` CROSS JOIN `8s8_customer_group` AS `cg` CROSS JOIN `8s8_core_website` AS `cw` INNER JOIN `8s8_core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id INNER JOIN `8s8_core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_produ
 ct_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_index_group_price` AS `gp` ON gp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND gp.website_id = cw.website_id AND gp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 121 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 121 AND tas_tax_class_i
 d.store_id = cs.store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `ta_price_type` ON ta_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price_type.attribute_id = 123 AND ta_price_type.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 75 AND ta_price.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_price.attribute_id = 76 AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 77 AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_produ
 ct_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `8s8_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id INNER JOIN `8s8_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='bundle') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (ta_price_type.value=0) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price_type` = VALUES(`price_type`), `special_price` = VALUES(`special_price`), `tier_percent` = VALUES(`tier_percent`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`
), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`), `group_price_percent` = VALUES(`group_price_percent

girachac_magen80 size:278MB

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to get on top of this problem, and get back 'online'. Of course I am trying to get professional help, but at the same time I want to learn so I thought it would be worth asking on here! Thank you very much. Rene.

Comment: Shared hosting services will often remove Magento from operation as they find it to be a _poorly written script_. Magento is resource intensive and doesn't play well on shared servers. The usual cure is to find a hosting service that a) understands providing Magento the resources it needs, b) understands how to run Magento on shared servers. So, unless this is from a third party module acting up and is only a mostly stock install of Magento, Siteground owes you a really big answer to "What Gives?" as they claim to know how to host Magento in a manner so it will run on shared servers.

Comment: I assume the query is made by the magentos price indexer, to answer the question. But @FiascoLabs is right. You need another hoster.

Answer (score 2):

This scripts reads many data from Database and its normal to cause some performance issues. So my suggestion is; use a seperate server that dedicate to only database. I mean use a database server. You can get one easily from digitalocean.

My second suggestion is; rewrite script completely from scracth and configure it to run part by part. It will reduce performance consuming.
If you pull out so many data from database in the same time its normal to cause performance issues whether you use high performance servers or not.

Also; Siteground has a poor Magento support and yes their servers are also sucks. They have good advertisings around everywhere but all about their support is just copy and past. You will get better support on Digitalocean even they don't have to answer your question they are looking a solution and telling you the way. No reason to not to love them <3